# how to update data in mysql when user share post on facebook using Facebook SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to update my database when user share post on fb. I am using Facebook SDK for JAVASCRIPT.

My Code Is:-

```
   <script>
        document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
          FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            display: 'popup',
            href: 'url goes here',
          }, function(response){
              if (response && response.post_id) {
                      //ajax code goes here for database update
                    } else {
                      alert('oops post was not published');
                    }
          });
        }
        </script>
```

Button Code-

```
    <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="url goes here" 
    data-layout="button" data-size="large">
    </div>
```

I am able to share the post but how to update the mysql data when user successfully sharesthe post

Comment: see my answer. what is the use case for this btw? why do you want to update the database if the user shared something?

Comment: @luschn actually i am working on a project which rewards the user when the user successfully share the posts

Comment: That is not even allowed ... you can not reward the user for sharing in any way. You should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) before you proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You will only know if the user shared something if you authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission. That permission needs to get reviewed by Facebook, and Facebook will not approve it just for this, i´m afraid.

In other words: It is not possible.